# Protobuf find the message type

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, decode, protobuf.js

I have written websocket client in node js which will receive from message from server in protobuff encoded format.

**data.proto**

```
message test1{
    required int32 id = 1;
}

message test2{
    required int32 id = 1; // 1
    required string tok = 2;
}

message test4 { 
    required int32 id = 1; // 3
    repeated string asdf = 2;
}
```

The websocket server will send different messages recursively **test1**, **test2**, **test3**. Since the incoming messages are encoded I could not able to find which proto message structure needs to be called to decode the message. Is there a way to find proto message type before calling decode?